# Threads getting blocked in Jackson's SerializerCache

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, jackson

I was load-testing my Spring Boot 1.3.5 application when I came across an odd behaviour. Upon increasing the number of requests to, say, 5000 requests/second, threads started to block on Jackson's `SerializerCache`. At first I thought it could be some misconfiguration on my side, so I created a fresh, minimal application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DojoRestApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DojoRestApplication.class, args);
  }

  @RestController
  public static final class StatusController {
    @RequestMapping(method = GET, path = "/status", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<ApplicationStatus> get() {
      final ApplicationStatus result = new ApplicationStatus();
      result.setTimestamp(Instant.now());
      result.setVersion("1.0.0");
      return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
    }
  }

  public static final class ApplicationStatus {
    private Instant timestamp;
    private String version;

    public Instant getTimestamp() {
      return timestamp;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
      return version;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Instant timestamp) {
      this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
      this.version = version;
    }
  }
}
```

Upon throwing a bunch of simultaneous requests at the `/status` endpoint here's what JProfiler tells me:

[image: JProfiler]

I took a thread dump and almost all the threads are stuck at this:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.SerializerCache.untypedValueSerializer(java.lang.Class) (line: 84)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._findExplicitUntypedSerializer(java.lang.Class) (line: 1124)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.hasSerializerFor(java.lang.Class, java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference) (line: 422)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.canSerialize(java.lang.Class, java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference)
org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.canWrite(java.lang.Class, org.springframework.http.MediaType) (line: 178)
org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.canWrite(java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.Class, org.springframework.http.MediaType)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(java.lang.Object, org.springframework.core.MethodParameter, org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpRequest, org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse) (line: 215)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(java.lang.Object, org.springframework.core.MethodParameter, org.springframework.web.method.support.ModelAndViewContainer, org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest) (line: 183)
org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(java.lang.Object, org.springframework.core.MethodParameter, org.springframework.web.method.support.ModelAndViewContainer, org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest) (line: 81)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest, org.springframework.web.method.support.ModelAndViewContainer, java.lang.Object[ ]) (line: 126)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod) (line: 832)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod) (line: 743)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, java.lang.Object)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) (line: 961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) (line: 895)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) (line: 967)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) (line: 858)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) (line: 622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) (line: 843)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) (line: 729)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) (line: 292)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) (line: 207)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain) (line: 52)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) (line: 240)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) (line: 207)
org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain) (line: 99)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain) (line: 107)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) (line: 240)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) (line: 207)
org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain) (line: 87)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain) (line: 107)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) (line: 240)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) (line: 207)
org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain) (line: 77)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain) (line: 107)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) (line: 240)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) (line: 207)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain) (line: 121)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain) (line: 107)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) (line: 240)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) (line: 207)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) (line: 212)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) (line: 106)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) (line: 502)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) (line: 141)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) (line: 79)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) (line: 88)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(org.apache.coyote.Request, org.apache.coyote.Response) (line: 522)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper) (line: 1095)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper, org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketStatus) (line: 672)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun() (line: 1502)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run() (line: 1458)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (line: 1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (line: 617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run() (line: 61)
java.lang.Thread.run() (line: 745)
```

It seems strange to me that this is happening, as it looks like Jackson is creating a serializer every single request or something. What can be causing this behaviour? Is this on Jackson's or Spring Boot's side (or mine, though I didn't really change any config)? The Jackson version in use is 2.6.6 (Spring Boot 1.3.5's default).

Comment: Which version of Jackson is this with? If 2.4 or earlier, I would recommend upgrade, ideally to 2.7(.5)

Comment: 2.6.6, which is Spring Boot's default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson is not creating a new serializer for each request; that specific line is small synchronization block for simple `get` lookup from a `HashMap`. It would seem odd to have that synchronization to last anywhere long enough for threads to contest it. So I wonder if this might be an artifact of profiling.

However: that method itself should not be called much after `ObjectMapper` gets called by first thread(s); after initial lookup succeeds, serializer is added into shared map, but further `SerializerProvider`s that get constructed should get a read-only copy with newly bound serializer. So it is puzzling why it would be accessed continuously.

Perhaps you could file an issue at `jackson-databind` issue tracker? 2.6 is new enough that the behavior probably still exists in 2.7 as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've opened it at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1275.

Comment: Looks like issue has been resolved in 2.7.x; a simple test showed that call to the synchronized only occurs for the first access. So situation should be much better.

Comment: I am having this exact issue but my jackson version is 2.13.1

Comment: @AlexR In vast majority of cases problems with cache sync are symptoms of  other bigger problem(s) -- specifically that of not reusing `ObjectMapper`s (or ObjectWriters as better alternative). So consider that as a signal to look into possibly wasteful usage, not the root cause.